# I entered the correct value but the wrong value is printed

Tags: java

I entered the correct value but the wrong value is printed. (*Quotient is displayed up to the first decimal place.)

```
System.out.printf ("What is quotient of %d / %d ? ", n1, n2);
double answer1 = s.nextDouble();  //enter quotient

System.out.printf("What is remainder of %d / %d ? ", n1, n2);
double answer2 = s.nextDouble();  //enter remainder

if ((quotient == answer1) && (((n1-(quotient*n2)) == answer2)))
  System.out.print("Correct!");

else {  System.out.print("Incorrect: ");  //error point I think
System.out.printf("%d / %d = %f, Remainder: %f \n", n1, n2, quotient, (n1-(quotient*n2)));   }
```

When the problem is 6/7, if I enter the right answer 0.8 and the rest 0.4, "Incorrect: 6/7 = 0.800000, remainder: 0.400000" is displayed instead of "Correct!" What should I do?

Comment: But `6/7` is not `0.8`?

Comment: instead of comparing with == you can calculate the difference of the two

Comment: Yes. Normally, 6/7 is not 0.8, but in this program it only divides to the first decimal point..

Comment: What does mean "you can calculate the difference of the two." ? I dont understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to floating point operations and precision. The difference may be in the 10th place after the comma. Therefore you should not compare floats with `==` but check if their difference is below a certain threshold.

```
double a = ...;
double b = ...;

if (Math.abs(a-b) < 0.0001) {
  //Consider as equal
} else { 
  //Consider as unequal
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your help, I could solve the problem. You’re awesome! B-)

Answer (score 0):

Even though two floating point variables(say a & b) have the same value mathematically, their equality might not return true,i.e, `a == b` might not be true. Hence, we find the difference to see if the difference is negligible. So, try the following:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = 6, n2 = 7;

        System.out.printf ("What is quotient of %d / %d ? ", n1, n2);
        double answer1 = s.nextDouble();  //enter quotient

        System.out.printf("What is remainder of %d / %d ? ", n1, n2);
        double answer2 = s.nextDouble();  //enter remainder

        double num = answer1 * n2 + answer2; //calculate user's number
        if (Math.abs(new Double(n1) - num) <= 0.1f)
            System.out.print("Correct!");
        else{
            System.out.print("Incorrect: ");  //error point I think
            double quotient = new Double(n1) / new Double(n2);
            double remainder = new Double(n1) - quotient * new Double(n2);
            System.out.printf("%d / %d = %f, Remainder: %f \n", n1, n2, quotient, remainder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand 'new Double' because I am a beginner, but thank you very much for your kind answers! It really helped a lot :D

Comment: It is used to convert `int` to `double`.

Comment: Avoid that kind of conversion. Cast instead. Your way of doing it introduces a lot of unnecessary overhead and bypasses caching mechanisms.

Comment: Yes you can do that too.

Comment: Oh I see! i got it